# How to implement Auditing with DynamoDB in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb, auditing

I've dynamoDB database, in which I've a table named `user`. I want to log auditing (`CreatedBy`, `LastModifiedBy`, `CreatedDate`, `LastModifiedDate`)in this table.

I've found JPA auditing ([from here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-data-jpa-auditing-automatically-the-good-stuff)) and MongoDB auditing with annotations `@EnableJpaAuditing` and `@EnableMongoAuditing` respectively. But obviously they are not working with dynamoDB.

Here is my abstract class for auditing:

```
    @DynamoDBDocument
public abstract class PQSSAbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable{
    @CreatedBy
    @JsonIgnore
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @JsonIgnore
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @JsonIgnore
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private Date createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @JsonIgnore
    @DynamoDBAttribute
    private Date lastModifiedDate = new Date();

    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public String getLastModifiedBy() {
        return lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedBy(String lastModifiedBy) {
        this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    }

    public Date getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Date getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(Date lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }
}
```

I've assigned dates to respective fields but I've to set `createdBy` and `lastModifiedBy` depending on the logged in user. So I've to fetch the dynamically at runtime, when ever new entry is added into the database.
I know how to set these fields statically but the problem is how to make annotations aware of these changes at run time.

As I mentioned, I've found `AuditAware` for JPA and mongo. I need the same for dynamoDB.

Any help will be appreciated. As I'm new to Spring boot.

Comment: I would suggest you get that meta information from the Utils class. Apart from this, it's always good to have version field @DynamoDBVersionAttribute for optimistic locking, especially while auditing.
Use Spring data repo for dynamoDb to perform the crud operations

Comment: Sorry, but this is so high level explanation. can you please give an example?

Comment: I am also confused how it can be implemented. @YatiSawhney please provide an example for how it can be implemented. I am using dynamodb and extends repositories with crudrepository.

Answer (score 4):

The question is already some years old but if somebody has also that problem, following solution works..

The problem is, that `@EnableDynamoDBAuditing` and `@EnableDynamoDBRepositories` don't work properly together. To solve this problem you have to add both annotations to you configuration class, create `AuditorAware` and `DateTimeProvider` beans and add all your entities/documents to your `DynamoDBMappingContext` manually.

PersistenceConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableDynamoDBAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "userAuditing", dateTimeProviderRef = "dateAuditing")
@EnableDynamoDBRepositories(basePackages = "your.repository.package.name")
public class PersistenceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AuditorAware<String> userAuditing() {
        return () -> Optional.of("TestUser"); //get username from SecurityContext
    }

    @Bean
    public DateTimeProvider dateAuditing() {
        return CurrentDateTimeProvider.INSTANCE;
    }

    @Bean
    public DynamoDBMappingContext dynamoDBMappingContext() {
        DynamoDBMappingContext mappingContext = new DynamoDBMappingContext();

        //add your 'entities' manually 
        mappingContext.getPersistentEntity(YourEntity.class); 

        return mappingContext;
    }

    // do further configuration stuff...
}
```

YourEntity.java

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "YourEntity")
public class YourEntity {
   @CreatedDate
   @DynamoDBAttribute
   @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
   private LocalDateTime createdOn;

   @CreatedBy
   @DynamoDBAttribute
   private String createdBy;

   @LastModifiedDate
   @DynamoDBAttribute
   @DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
   private LocalDateTime updatedOn;

   @LastModifiedBy
   @DynamoDBAttribute
   private String updatedBy;

   // add further properties...
}
```

I know that there are some other solutions like `@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp` and the usage of their strategies, but in my mind that's the cleanest solution regarding the use of spring.

Comment: how to set those createdBy and lastModifiedBy as dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

The annotaion `@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp` can be used along with `DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy` to audit the item.

**Strategy CREATE (Use this for Create audit):-**

```
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy=DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.CREATE)
 public Date getCreatedDate() { return createdDate; }
 public void setCreatedDate(Date createdDate) { this.createdDate = createdDate; }
```

**Strategy ALWAYS (Use this if you want last modified date):-**

```
 @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp(strategy=DynamoDBAutoGenerateStrategy.ALWAYS)
 public Date getLastUpdatedDate() { return lastUpdatedDate; }
 public void setLastUpdatedDate(Date lastUpdatedDate) { this.lastUpdatedDate = lastUpdatedDate; }
```

If you want both create timestamp and last modified timestamps, please create two different attributes. One attribute should use CREATE strategy and other one should use ALWAYS strategy.

[AutoGeneratedTimeStamp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBAutoGeneratedTimestamp.html)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response, but my problem is not saving dates, I want to save `CreatedBy` and `LastModifiedBy`.

Comment: CreatedBy and LastModifiedBy are user ids which you need to set in your application.

Comment: yes, But in my application, different users logs in and the updates they database, so I want to set these fields by getting currently logged in user dynamically.

Comment: I know how to set these fields statically but the problem is how to make annotations aware of these changes at run time?